# protected content in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<?php       
if($user_authorized == 1){
//some HTML/PHP code is VISIBLE to user
}
else{
echo"You are not authorized!";
}
?>
```

Now the data I want to make visible to the user needs extreme level of privacy (it is some legal content). If i use HTML, it is being displayed in the source code even if the user is not authorized. if i use PHP, it is almost impossible for me to format the content, as it needs `<h1><h2>` at several places etc etc...

Is it possible that I save the data in database and then retrieve it only if the user is authorized? If so, will I have formatting options?

What other options do I have to achieve the same?

Comment: You need to learn how to separate your php code from your html templates. I recommend reading up on the MVC pattern, it's very common.

Comment: Why is it `almost impossible to format the content`? Simply use heredoc or similar to define a string of your content, then echo it; or `?>` to drop out of PHP, show your formatted content, then `<?php` back to PHP fr the closing `}`

Comment: You can do it in php itself, since php can serve html.. are you sending the user to this page or are you dynamically updating contents of the page with result after checking for authentication?

Comment: No server code is visible to the user

Comment: @MarkBaker! There are some 400 pages of content, just for one type of user and there are going to be some 30+ types of users. I know dropping out the PHP and then continuing it after HTML, but it's again hectic to format

Comment: Read about php session login :) this should help you archive what you want, then come back if you have any issues. And yes its possible to save the data on a database and show if user is authorized, add MySQL to your php list of learning.

Comment: @MarkBaker however I don't know much about heredoc. Will check it out.

Comment: @BoobyTrappedProgrammer I am sending the user to this page and on this page the authentication is being checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, from your comments it seems that the only problem that you face here is formatting and as suggested by @Mark Baker, you should use heredoc for the formatting..

```
<?php       
$authenticatedText = <<<HTML
//as much HTML as you want here.. you can mix php variables as well by just saying $variable name
<table></table>
HTML;

if($user_authorized == 1){
//some HTML/PHP code is VISIBLE to user
echo $authenticatedText;
}
else{
echo"You are not authorized!";
}
?>
```

You can also look into templating system in php, for example smarty templating engine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have a problem really. The php will only deliver the code in the true outcome. To use html either echo out the html code OR (more simply) escape out to your html:

```
<?php       
if($user_authorized == 1){
//some HTML/PHP code is VISIBLE to user
echo "<table ...>";
echo "<tr><td><h1></h1></td></tr>"; // etc. OR simply escape out to the html as follows:
?>
<table ...>
<tr><td><h1></h1></td></tr>
</table>
<?php
}
else{
echo"You are not authorized!";
}
?>
```

The client (browser) only recieves what the PHP sends it. So users will only see the code they are meant to.

Comment: What do you mean `formatting is not being resolved`? You have complete control over the formatting

Comment: If the user is not authorized, the HTML portion (out of the php tags) will appear in the source code. is that right?

Comment: If the user is not authorised, all that will appear in the source code via their browser will be: "You are not authorised"

Comment: The table (in my example) will only be presented to the browser if the  ($user_authorised == 1) is true.